# Boomi error: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: boomi

I unable to understand what the error is about when trying to the run process.
Logs:

> Unexpected error executing process:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 [Response
>   Message: Forbidden, Name: Forbidden, Code: 403] Unknown failure Index:
>   0, Size: 0 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: Still having issues with this? Are there any more details from the logs you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

The process you're running is attempting to call a web service or access a page. It doesn't have the correct entitlements, so the server is returning a 403 error. The process doesn't know how to handle that and is throwing an exception. Maybe someone can give you a better answer if you include the source code of the process you're trying to run.

Comment: Yes it is the issue with api call, but i used same for the other jobs which is working fine for other objects.

Comment: Got me. Maybe you're running this one under a different user ID, or it's not sending the correct authentication headers, or something. Hard to say without the code.

Comment: https://url/api/suppliers/{0}/addresses  
this is the url to which i'm doing get api call, using valid api key and header are good since as it works for other objects.